# how to Insert Primary key instead of name column in database

Tags: php

I am developing a hotel reservation system in PHP using MySQL.

I want to know how to insert primary key value instead of name in the database. user select hotel name from drop down , instead of putting hotel name in database I want to insert `hotel_id`.

where I have a page named with ADD New room where the user will add new rooms.

table related to add new room page is: room in MySQL

in that page, I have a form where the user has to select hotel name from a select tag which is populated dynamically from a database table named as hotels.

I want to insert `hotel_id` which is a foreign key in room table  correspondence to the selected hotel name

Below is the code which shows select tag populated with the hotel name.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Hotel Name</label> 
        <select class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
        <?php
            $sel_cus = "select * from hotels ";
            $res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_cus);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {
        ?>  
                <option value="<?php  echo $row['hotel_name']; ?>"><?php   echo $row['hotel_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
            } 
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>
```

when i insert room record in database using below code it insert hotel name instead of `hotel_id`. I want to insert `hotel_id` in `room` table.
Please guide me with code example. Thanks

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $hotel_name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = date('m-dd-yy');
    $query = "INSERT INTO  room (Hotel_Id, date) 
           VALUES ('$hotel_name ','$date')";
}
```

Comment: Pass the `hotel_id` instead or, ***if*** names are unique do a `SELECT [...] WHERE name = ?` by the `hotel_name` to get the `hotel_id`.

Comment: `INSERT INTO  room (Hotel_Id,date) (select id, '$date' from hotels where hotel_name = '$hotel_name')`

Comment: Also change  dropdowwn to `<option value="<?php  echo $row['hotel_id']; ?>"><?php   echo $row['hotel_name'];?></option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the option value. Currently you are using hotel_name as option value, change this to hotel_id and you should be fine.

```
<option value="<?php  echo $row['hotel_id']; ?>"><?php   echo $row['hotel_name'];?></option>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . May Allah shows his countless blessing upon you